# List of connectable events of gi.repository.Notify object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygobject, gobject, pynotify

I need to list all available connectable events which can be connected with Python gi.repository.Notify object eg. `obj.connect("event", callback_fun)`. How do I print list of "connectable" events of gi.repository.Notify object? I have tried with `dir(obj)` and `obj.props` but couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, what you want. A "notify" signal will be emitted, when any of GObject's properties changes. You can get a list of all properties with [`GObject.list_properties()`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GObject-2.0/functions.html#GObject.list_properties).

If you need a list of signals, you can use [`GObject.signal_list_names()`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GObject-2.0/functions.html#GObject.signal_list_names). But AFAIK you can not get signal handler prototypes from this list. Reading the docs is a much better approach.